# getting the average of serial port data

Tags: python, serial-port

i have a python code which reads serial data through RS232

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 2400, timeout=1)

while True:
str1 = ser.read(1)
if str1 == '':
    print 'no data on line'
else:
    print str1
```

this returns me

```
no data on line
no data on line
no data on line
no data on line
206
210
212
200
```

it's mic-reading values
let's assume those numbers are degrees to move a motor 
i want to get the avarage number to move the motor to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import serial
import time
data_sum = []
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 2400, timeout=1)

while True:
    str1 = ser.read(1)
    if str1 == '':
        print 'no data on line'
    else:
        data_sum.append(int(str1)

ave = sum(data_sum)/len(data_sum)
```

Comment: what's the difference between append and extend ?

Comment: append adds an element to a list.  extend adds a list to a list -- not as a sublist, but just 'extending' the list

Comment: I just fixed code by adding data_sum at the top as an empty list.  Each line of data is appended to the list.  In the end, the average is taken